# Differentiating a two variable function's matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So, I have

$F: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2,$ and the matrix $F(x,y)=[x\ln(y),xy]$

And I'm to calculate the matrix derivative at point $a=[1, e]$.

Now, I somewhat know how to calculate approximations at points and such, and partial derivatives, but I'm not sure at all how I can derive matrix function of two variables or what I'm supposed to do here. The matrices $F(x,y)$ and $a$ are $1\times2$ matrices instead of $2\times1$, but I'm not sure how to make it look proper with the writing language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting $F(x,y) = (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$, the matrix derivate is the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant):
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} && \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} && \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}
\end{matrix}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\ln y && x/y\\
y && x
\end{matrix}
\right).
\end{equation}
When you evaluate it at point $(x,y) = (1,e)$, it results
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 && 1/e\\
e && 1
\end{matrix}
\right).
\end{equation}

Comment: Do I need to reverse-engineer the matrix or what if I want to further linearize the function at $a$?

Comment: You have linearized the function already. You have the differential and this is exactly its definition: to be the best linearization. So,$$F(x,y)\approx F(x_0,y_0)+(x-x_0,y-y_0)\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1/e\\
        e & 1
        \end{pmatrix}$$